# RegExp: match a string separated by semicolons at start or between semicolons or at the end of the string

Tags: javascript, regex

Given these strings:

```
1;2;3
2;1;3
2;3;1
```

I need to match/find the `1` in it (for the sake of simplicity, the `1` can be any string).

Came up with this pattern as a partial solution, which at the moment suits my needs (because it returns true on regexp.test()):

```
(?:^|;)(1)(?=;|$)
```

It matches all the ocurrences of `1` but:

the second and the third result has the semicolon attached in front of it like this:

```
;1
```

How could I rewrite the pattern to get rid of the semicolon?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, there are no lookbehinds in javascript. Capture and remove (`matches[1]`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't - JavaScript doesn't support [lookbehind assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) which you'd need for this.

But you can simply access `match[1]` to get the contents of the first [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) of your regex `match` object.

Comment: I think I got confused by the explanation of the non capturing parentheses on the [MozillaDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-non-capturing-parentheses), thought that (?:;) wouldn't match the semicolon. :|

Answer (score 1):

Just use `regexp.match()[1]` to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
^([^1]*)1([^1]*)*$
```

If I use your cases, it works!! This url can help you: http://www.metriplica.com/es/recursos/expresiones-regulares

Comment: Doesn't work. Try to put a '0' in the 'Texto de reemplazo :' input and than hit the 'REEMPLAZAR' button. The whole string get replaced. Not only the 1 in it.

Comment: Expresión: ^([^1]*)1([^1]*)*$
Cadena a probar : 2;3;1;
Texto de reemplazo : $10$2     (try too $1AAAAA$2)
Click on "Reemplazar"

Comment: Sorry, but not what I was looking for. Thanks anyway.